# Return something before Parallel.Foreach finishes executing

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

```
public bool SampleMethod()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(List, Val =>
    {
        // execute some time consuming code
    });
    return true;
}
```

I noticed `Parallel.Foreach` is blocking the thread, until all the tasks in foreach loop are completed.

For the method above, I want to return true right away, even if the operations in `Parallel.foreach` block are still executing (they should still run in background until all of them are finished).

Is this possible?

Comment: Use Task API to take the execution in Background, Parallel APIs are not meant for this purpose. You can start the Task and not wait for them to finish and return true after starting all the Tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your parallel operation in another thread:

```
public bool SampleMethod()
{
     Task.Run(() => {
                       Parallel.ForEach(List, Val =>
                       {
                          // execute some time consuming code
                       });
                    });
    return true;
}
```

This will start the task in a separate thread and return `true` without waiting it's finished.

Comment: Would the separate thread the background thread to keep working even id the process returns and exit or is it a foreground thread, which would need main process thread to not exit